# Jest: resolves return undefined from Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, jestjs, babel-polyfill

I am using jest for testing. I want to test the return of my function:

```
const xml2js = require('xml2js')

const parser = new xml2js.Parser()

function opmlParser(xmlData) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    parser.parseString(xmlData, (err, data) => {
      if (err !== null && data !== null) reject(err)
      resolve({})
    })
  })
}
```

The promise resolves `{}` in order to be in simple test case.

So, I want to test to following function, and I expect the result to be a promise containing `{}`.
I have the following code:

```
const fs = require('fs');

test('minimal-opml', () => {
  const xmlData = fs.readFileSync('test/opml-parser/opml/test1.opml')
  return expect(opmlParser(xmlData)).resolves.toEqual({})
})
```

As the Jest documentation say, I shoud use `resolves` statement before matching result and use `return`.

But, I got an issue:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toEqual' of undefined
```

`resolves` return `undefined`, so I can't continue to test values.

I tried to add `global.Promise = require.requireActual('promise')`, but stills not work.

Do you have any idea what wrong I am doing?

Comment: My answer was incorrect, sorry, I must have been thinking of a different testing framework. FWIW, when people are trying to help you, even if they're wrong, "Whatever this don't even answer my question." is hardly a polite response.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to be rude, I just wanted to mark the point that your answer didn't match the question. But, yes the formulation was bad. Sorry, and thank you for trying to help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `resolves` methode is avalaible from 20.0.0+. So it is not already avalable. [source](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/expect.html#available-in-jest-2000)

This is why it return `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few issues in checking for an error in the `opmlParser` function. You want to check if there *is* an error and reject, else resolve.

Try this (brackets for clarity, and you may need to refine this to your specific case):

```
if (err !== null) {
  reject(err)
} else {
  resolve({})
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I still have the issue. I edited my post with your fix.

Comment: @Frilox: I've rolled back that edit. That's not how SO works. If you edit answers into the question, the answer becomes nonsense, looking like it just repeats what's in the question.